# Expanding by partial fractions

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Problem:
Expand by partial fractions.
$$ \dfrac{x^3-1}{\left( x^2 + x + 1\right)^2 } $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{x^3-1}{\left( x^2 + x + 1\right)^2 } &=
 \dfrac{Ax+B}{ x^2 + x + 1} + \dfrac{Cx+D}{\left( x^2 + x + 1\right)^2 } \\
x^3 - 1 &= (Ax+B)(x^2+x+1) + Cx + D \\
x^3 - 1 &= Ax^3 + Ax^2 + Ax + Bx^2 + Bx + B + Cx + D \\
x^3 - 1 &= Ax^3 + (A+B)x^2 + (A+B+C)x + B + D \\
A &= 1 \\
- 1 &= (A+B)x + (A+B+C)x + B + D \\
A + B &= 0 \\
1 + B &= 0 \\
B &= -1 \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to find $C$ and $D$.
\begin{align*}
A + B + C &= 0 \\
1 - 1 + C &= 0 \\
C &= 0 \\
B + D &= -1 \\
-1 + D &= -1 \\
D &= 0
\end{align*}
Hence the solution is:
$$ \dfrac{x^3-1}{\left( x^2 + x + 1\right)^2 } =
 \dfrac{x - 1}{ x^2 + x + 1} + \dfrac{0}{\left( x^2 + x + 1\right)^2 } $$
which is simplified too:
$$ \dfrac{x^3-1}{\left( x^2 + x + 1\right)^2 } = \dfrac{x - 1}{ x^2 + x + 1} $$
However, this answer seems wrong to me because it has only one term. Is the answer right?

Comment: For a shortcut, remember that $\,x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)\,$.

Comment: You will find it helpful  to know the factorizations for the "sum" and "difference of two cubes" and, in general, for $ \ a^n - b^n \   $ (and for $ \ a^n + b^n \ \ , $ when $ \ n \ $ is odd), as they turn up in many sorts of problems.

Answer (score 3):

It's correct. You just simplified $$\frac{x^3-1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}=\frac{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}=\frac{x-1}{x^2+x+1}$$ in a very complicated way

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac{x^3-1}{\left( x^2 + x + 1\right)^2 }= \frac{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{ (x^2 + x + 1)^2}=\frac{x-1}{x^2 + x + 1} $$

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

and

$x^2 + x + 1$ could not be factorize